# How to make span non editable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a span inside an iframe. I want that span to be non-editable, but doesn't work. I tried everything: pointer-events, contenteditable. Nothing works. Help!!

```
  $('#tokens-menu-list').on('click', 'li', function() {
        var token       = $(this).attr('data-value');
        var token_style = "border-radius: 5px; background-color: #99CDE1;padding: 5px;cursor: context-menu;";
        $(iframeDocument).find('body').insertAtCaret("<span class='token-item' style='" + token_style + "'>" + token + "</span>");
        $('#tokens-menu').css('display', 'none');
    });



  $(iframeDocument).find('body').on('click', 'span.token-item', function() {
            $(this).css('pointer-events', 'none');
          });
```

Comment: what is `iframeDocument` ?

Answer (score 0):

Add `contents()` to be able to select  iframe elements :

```
 $(iframeDocument).contents().find('body').on('click', 'span.token-item', function(e) {
       e.preventDefault(); // This should stop the click
     // But also, make sure that
      $(this).attr("contenteditable", "false"); // This makes sure that the content can't be edited
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like

```
$(iframeDocument).find('body').on('click', 'span.token-item', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // This should stop the click
    // But also, make sure that
    $(this).attr("contenteditable", "false"); // This makes sure that the content can't be edited
});
```

Tell me if this works.

Good luck!

Comment: @coffeeak Hmm... Then the bug would be in the code you haven't posted. Would you mind making a jsfiddle or codepen demonstrating the bug?